# WPF - bottom controls gets cut in grid rows

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've created a form using WPF, all the layout is built using grid and stack panels. It worked well in version 1.0.1, in version 1.0.2 I added a new row with a combobox. Surprisingly it resulted in bottom controls in rows 2, 3 and 4 getting cut (partially obscured) - but only when I run the app, during editing it looks fine. I wonder what is the problem?

Here is the xaml code:

```xml
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" 
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:EnumConverter x:Key="EnumConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    
    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="Col1" Width="275"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        
        <Label Grid.Row="0"
               Grid.Column="0" 
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               Content="xxxx" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               FontWeight="Bold" 
               FontSize="22"
               Height="50"
               VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Margin="0,10">
            <Label Content="Template:" Width="100"/>
            <ComboBox Width="270"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TemplateNames}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=TemplateName}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,0,10,0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Horizontal units:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100"/>
                <local:IntTextBox Text="{Binding Path=HorizontalUnits}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Width="30"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Vertrical units:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100"/>
                <local:IntTextBox Text="{Binding Path=VerticalUnits}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Width="30"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Levels:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100"/>
                <local:IntTextBox Text="{Binding Path=HeightUnits}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Width="30"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Orientation:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="25">
                    <RadioButton Content="Horizontal"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 IsChecked="{Binding UnitPlanOrientation, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static data:UnitPlanOrientation.Horizontal}}"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="Vertical"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 Margin="5,0"
                                 IsChecked="{Binding UnitPlanOrientation, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static data:UnitPlanOrientation.Vertical}}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Purpose:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="25">
                    <RadioButton Content="Infiltration"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 IsChecked="{Binding TankPurpose, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static data:TankPurpose.Infiltration}}"/>
                    <RadioButton Content="Attenuation"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 Margin="5,0"
                                 IsChecked="{Binding TankPurpose, Converter={StaticResource EnumConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static data:TankPurpose.Attenuation}}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>


        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0,0,10,0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Surface level:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="120"/>
                <local:DoubleTextBox Text="{Binding Path=GroundLevel, StringFormat=N2}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Width="60"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Groundwater level:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="120"/>
                <local:DoubleTextBox Text="{Binding Path=WaterLevel, StringFormat=N2}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Width="60"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Label Content="Tank ceiling level:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="120"/>
                <local:DoubleTextBox Text="{Binding Path=TankTopLevel, StringFormat=N2}"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Width="60"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>

        <GroupBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Header="Tank Info:" Margin="0,5,0,5" Padding="0,6">
            <Grid Margin="-6,0,0,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Col1, Path=Width}"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Net volume [m³]:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="110"/>
                        <local:DoubleTextBox Text="{Binding Path=NetVolume, StringFormat=N2}"
                                             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                             Width="60"
                                             IsEnabled="False"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Gross volume [m³]:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="110"/>
                        <local:DoubleTextBox Text="{Binding Path=GrossVolume, StringFormat=N2}"
                                             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                             Width="60"
                                             IsEnabled="False"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Width [m]:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="80"/>
                        <local:DoubleTextBox Text="{Binding Path=Width, StringFormat=N2}"
                                             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                             Width="60"
                                             IsEnabled="False"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Length [m]:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="80"/>
                        <local:DoubleTextBox Text="{Binding Path=Length, StringFormat=N2}"
                                             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                             Width="60"
                                             IsEnabled="False"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Height [m]:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="80"/>
                        <local:DoubleTextBox Text="{Binding Path=Height, StringFormat=N2}"
                                             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                             Width="60"
                                             IsEnabled="False"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>

        <GroupBox Grid.Row="4"
                  Grid.Column="0" 
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                  Header="Bedding:" 
                  Margin="0,5,0,5" 
                  Padding="0,6">
            <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="Top:" Width="60"/>
                    <local:DoubleTextBox Text="{Binding Path=GravelTopThickness, StringFormat=N2}"
                                     Width="40"/>
                    <ComboBox Width="250"
                              Margin="10,0"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BeddingTypes}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=GravelSideTopType}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="Side:" Width="60"/>
                    <local:DoubleTextBox Text="{Binding Path=GravelSideThickness, StringFormat=N2}"
                                     Width="40"/>
                    <ComboBox Width="250"
                              Margin="10,0"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BeddingTypes}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=GravelSideTopType}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="Bottom:" Width="60"/>
                    <local:DoubleTextBox Text="{Binding Path=GravelBottomThickness, StringFormat=N2}"
                                     Width="40"/>
                    <ComboBox Width="250"
                              Margin="10,0"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BeddingTypes}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=GravelBottomType}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </GroupBox>

        <GroupBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Header="Additional elements:" Margin="0,5,0,5" Padding="0,5">
            <Grid Margin="-6,0,0,0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Col1, Path=Width}"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Content="Shaft type:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="110"/>
                        <ComboBox Width="150"
                              Margin="10,0"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ShaftTypes}"
                              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ShaftType}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>

        <Label Grid.Row="6"
               Grid.Column="0"
               Content="{Binding Path=AppVersion}" 
               FontSize="10"
               Foreground="Gray"/>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="6" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Button Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="5"
                    Margin="5,0"
                    Padding="10,2"
                    Content="OK"
                    ToolTip="{Binding Path=ValidationInfo}"
                    ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled="True"
                    Command="{Binding Path=Create}"
                    IsDefault="True"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="5"
                    Content="Cancel"
                    Margin="5,0,0,0"
                    Padding="10,2"
                    Click="Cancel_Click" 
                    IsCancel="True"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: bottom controls in rows 2, 3 and 4 are cut]

Comment: You have set `Height="*"` for every row so each row will try it's best to take maximum space it can get. but when window opens and each row takes her space the content of row doesn't have enough space to be fit in fully.

Comment: What should happen when there is not enough space for the controls to be drawn ?

Comment: if you resize the window you'll see content will start showing up. So maybe use a parent `ScrollViewer` or set height or minHeight manually of rows or use some other way so that it's always truly responsive layout.

Comment: @RaoHammasHussain I expected that setting Height = "*" for each row should handle this situation. The window is not resizeable, it opens and stays the same.

Comment: @adam.k that's the reason because rows are trying to take max space but they don't have any space that's why content collapse. Use a parent ScrollViewer !

Comment: @NawedNabiZada since window's size is also automatic using SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" I expected it should work properly, there should never be a situation that there is not enough space for controls.

Comment: @adam.k this will always be a problem on small screens where it won't get enough space ! so as i said use a scroll viewer or change layout way.

Comment: Height="*" means divide the space equally between the rows. You could use Height="Auto" for the top rows and let the last one or the biggest one have "*" and use a ScrollViewer.

Comment: thanks for the advice and explanation @RaoHammasHussain. Eventually wrapping it all into `ScrollViewer` did the job.

Comment: thanks @NawedNabiZada for the advice and explanation too

Comment: I just tried out your xaml (replacing all DoubleBlaControls with textboxes and removing the converters). Nothing is cut off when i run it. tipp for next time: try to make an example that other people can actually run.